# Can CNNs complete lines and contours?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, computer-vision, object-detection

Are there deep convolutional networks capable of recognizing two overlapping triangles in this image - or is this beyond the capabilities of CNNs?

[image]

And are there CNNs that can recogize two boxes connected by a line in this image?

[image]

If there are no CNNs that can do it: Are there other architectures that can?